# How to call local .dll files in Electron App

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

i have an issue how to call sample .dll files into my Electron App. I have sample .dll files in my folder, the thing is how to access my sample.dll file and how to call my sample.dll function and gets results. Any tutorials or steps to follow please sample code to start

Answer (score 38):

Calling into a `.dll` in Electron is no different to calling into one in plain NodeJS, which means you have two options, [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) or a [native Node addon](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/addons.html) that links with your `.dll` and exposes a JavaScript API. If you decide to create a native Node addon you will need to [build it to target Electron](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/).

Here are some links that cover these topics:

- [node-ffi vs. node extension for accessing existing C++ functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783023/node-ffi-vs-node-extension-for-accessing-existing-c-functionality)
- [Call C++ library from Node.js (Node addons / node-ffi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636017/call-c-library-from-node-js-node-addons-node-ffi)
- https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial
- https://blog.scottfrees.com/calling-native-c-dlls-from-a-node-js-web-app
- http://blog.scottfrees.com/building-an-asynchronous-c-addon-for-node-js-using-nan

Comment: thanks for ur feedback every blog has different way of methods cant get proper results

Comment: Node FFI won't compile with Node versions greater than Node 8. The project doesn't seem to be maintained any more sadly, so expect node gyp to throw errors if you NPM install with recent Node versions :(

Comment: @Malcolm Swaine Thanks for mentioning! What can we do in that case?

Comment: @poloapolo I'm using ffi-napi now and it seems to be working out well. I've had issues trying to invoke method calls from the renderer context, but from the ipc context it's doing the job. Repo is here https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi

Answer (score 3):

Electron-Edge helps to run .NET in Node.js on Electron.

You can [find it on GitHub](https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge). 

 [Here](https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge#how-to-integrate-c-code-into-nodejs-code) it is explained how to use dll files in it.(Scroll Down a little to find '*If you prefer to pre-compile your C# sources to a CLR assembly you can reference a CLR assembly from your Node.js code*...'