# Can .NET DLLs be created using Javascript or JScript.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, dll

I'm creating a video game that has single player and multiplayer. The single player is done in C# (Unity), and want to use Gamesparks BaaS that works on Javascript (NodeJS) for their server code.

Since I want the multiplayer server to be authoritative, I need the server code to run Javascript and the client will run C#, which means duplicated code

But, if I can create .NET dlls in Javascript I can reduce code duplication heavily by using those libraries in Unity and using the Javascript code on the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript (and by javascript I mean nodejs), along with c# and communicate between those two, you can use electron-edge. It helps you to run c# code using nodejs through Electron API.

Here is the link of their Github url: [Electron-Edge-documentation](https://github.com/kexplo/electron-edge)

You can also interact with dlls, using an creating your application as an electron app. You refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567446/how-to-call-local-dll-files-in-electron-app) where you will find some more details regarding it.